# Attach File into Access database using Classic ASP

Tags: file, ms-access, asp-classic, attachment

I have a form which contain some textfields and one attachment(type="file"). I am using MS Access 2010. When i am trying to insert form data into database i am getting error like An INSERT INTO query cannot contain a multi-valued field.I tried a lot and searched a lot but i couldn't figure out. I am able to do it using asp.net. But, My server supports only classical asp. Can anyone have any idea about this.

Comment: This probably has to do with the facts that you are trying to insert a file into the database. Files are binary and the rest of your values are just string or integers. Thus the `cannot contain a multi-valued field`. Why not store the files on disk and insert the filename in the database?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can make use of an MS Access attachment field using ADO. I believe you need to use DAO or ADO.Net. And I don't think DAO or ADO.net are available in Classic ASP.

Edit: I agree with Hansup, that you might be able to use DAO in VBScrip/Classic ASP but I'm finding it very difficult to find any information or examples. Here's a list of constants but this is for an older version of DAO. http://include.wutils.com/com-dll/constants/constants-DAO.htm